# Forge Viewer (SVF2) Not Receiving All Data

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a web application that uses the Forge Viewer with multiple SVF2 models.  In the application, I need both the object tree and geometry in order to do some further processing of the models once they are loaded.  A customer is frequently running into the case where for one or more models, either the geometry or object tree is not loaded (the application is not receiving the events and the data is also not available from the model object). The majority of the time, the issue doesn't occur, but it does happen frequently enough to be a problem.

Once a given model has been successfully loaded in a given user's browser, the user doesn't seem to have issues with that same model again unless the model is re-translated. So, it seems like browser caching helps prevent the issue, which seems to point to network issues getting the data initially as being at least part of the problem.

I have created a [repository](https://github.com/bencameron/svf2-loading-issue) to help reproduce the issue, which includes a simplified version of the code my application is using.

I'm trying to figure out next steps and need some guidance:

- What is a reasonable amount of time to wait for a model to fully load, given a fast, reliable internet connection?
- Is there a way to determine whether or not a model is still loading or has run into an error and should be abandoned? *model.loader.loading* seemed promising, but it looks like it is true even after loading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not reproduce the svf2 loading issue with your test case on my side.

You could try to clear viewer caches by adding an extra query string `?disableIndexedDb=true` to your viewer app URL to check if it's still reproducible. e.g. http://localhost:8080/?disableIndexedDb=true

If it persists, type this line in your Web Browser's dev console to see if any loading task is pending or stopped, and then report it to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` plus your model URN. We will help you pass it to our engineering team for insights.

```js
NOP_VIEWER.impl.geomCache().reportLoadingState()
```